# why InfluxDB web admin interface doesn't work with 1.1 release?

Tags: influxdb

I have installed influxDB on my vps, and i would like to use his Web admin interface.
Normaly i can acces it at the :8083 port but it doesn't work.

ps: I have activated the admin interface in influxDB.conf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having same issue. Installed 1.1 and not able to access admin interface despite changing the port several times. I was able to access the http endpoint though

With little probing, I realized that Influx DB was loading the default config all along and all my config changes were not getting applied. When I started the service with influxd -config influxdb.config the admin console started working.

PS: I am using it on windows.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Answer (score 6):

The Web Admin interface was [deprecated in version `1.1` of InfluxDB](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/commit/b6863b04d1be975b01f8cf239604d87e8c55b91d). It will be removed in `1.2` in favor of [Chronograf](https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf).

However in `1.1` you can still enable the Admin UI by updating the `[admin]` section of the InfluxDB configuration file.

```
[admin]
  enabled = true
  ...
```

Comment: I think the op says that he enabled the admin interface in the conf file. I tried to do the same and wasnt able to access the admin interface too.  So I don't think this answers his question

Comment: Ah, just noticed that. Let me investigate a bit more.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Seems to be working just fine for me

Comment: Yup, this is the solution. If you are using docker you can add an environment variable: INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true.

Comment: location of config file is /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf

Answer (score 2):

Initially, my installation (Win 7) worked well until I lost access to the web interface after an upgrade to 1.3.5. Even running an older version of Influxd would not fix it. I struggled for a while playing with all sorts of config changes and moved the installation out of the Programs folder with no help, until I found this:

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.3/tools/web_admin/

In version 1.3, the web admin interface is no longer available in InfluxDB. The interface does not run on port 8083 and InfluxDB ignores the [admin] section in the configuration file if that section is present. Chronograf replaces the web admin interface with improved tooling for querying data, writing data, and database management. See Chronograf’s transition guide for more information.

**I simply downloaded the Chronograph executable** and started it to connect on port :8888 which turned out to be a better user experience that the :8083 admin interface.

https://portal.influxdata.com/downloads